# Kendo Angular 2 dynamic tooltip

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, tooltip

I have a page using Kendo/Angular2.  The page has a lot of link/buttons.  When the user clicks on a link, a tooltip needs to appear next to the clicked link and any previous instances close.  The tooltip needs to use a template and display dynamic content based on the link that was clicked.   It would be nice to be able reuse a single tooltip control on the page.

Is it possible to get a demo of something like this?

Comment: I am facing the similar possibility. Have you found the solution yet? Please post it if u have.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a single kendo-popup control as a tooltip.  The offset property allows you to position the popup.  The offset is based on pageX and pageY values of the click event that opens the popup

Here are the relevant snippets from what I have:

component.html

```html
<kendo-popup [popupClass]="" *ngIf="tooltipVisible" [offset]="tooltipOffset">
    <div style="clear: both; padding: 2px;">
        {{tooltipValue}}
    </div>
</kendo-popup>

<button class="btn-link"
    (mouseover)="showTooltip($event,theData)" 
    (mouseout)="hideTooltip()"
                        style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">
                    {{theData}}
</button>
```

component.ts

```js
    tooltipOffset = { left: 0, top: 0 };
    tooltipVisible = false;
    tooltipValue = "";

    showTooltip(event: any, data: string) {
        this.tooltipOffset = { left: event.pageX + 4, top: event.pageY + 4 };
        this.tooltipVisible = true;
        this.tooltipValue = data;
    }

    hideTooltip() {
        this.tooltipVisible = false;
    }
```